# How to awk number into ranges and print the lower

Tags: awk, intervals

Can any one out there help me out on how to make use of awk to group set of values into ranges and print the lowest of each range as output.

Example file contains

```
2
3
4
6
7
8
10
12
13
14
16
18
19
```

starting from the minimum, I want to group them into interval of >=4 and print out the minimum

The group should be

```
f1rst group
2
3
4
6

second group
7
8
10

third group
12
13
14

fourth group
16
18
19
```

The output  should be minimum of each group

```
2
7
12
16
```

or print out the maximum each group

```
6
10
14
19
```

Comment: What is the logic to group numbers?

Comment: your groups seems to have 4 or 3 members, without a clear logic for deciding which has 4, which has 3. I thought it was "value between 1 and 4, between 5 and 8, etc" but the first group is between 2 and 6 ... (I also thought "ok, he wants between N and N+4" but then N+4 is inclusive? so it's really by group of 5? ex: 1 2 3 4 5 is a group ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping it by 4 using `awk`

Min

```
awk 'NR%4==1' file
2
7
13
19
```

Max

```
awk 'NR%4==0' file
6
12
18
```

---

To get the min and max value.

```
awk 'ORS=NR%4?FS:RS' file | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {min=$i<min||!min?$i:min; max=$i>max||!max?$i:max} print min,max;min=max=0}'
2 6
7 12
13 18
19 19
```

First `awk` group data, second gets `max` and `min`

Comment: this just prints every 4 lines (starting at line 1 in the first exemple, at line "0" (therefore line 4) in the second... it has nothing to do with grouping or printing the minimum value (unless the input is sorted), and doesn't group on the value of the input (it prints based on the line number, not the line's value)